# Finiteness of the homology of the Koszul complex

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, graded-rings, local-rings, filtered-modules

Let $A$ be a local noetherian commutative ring, let $x_1, \dots, x_r$ be elements of the maximal ideal of $A$, $I$ the ideal that they generate, $M$ a $A$-module of finite type such that $M/IM$ is of finite length.

The ideal $I$ defines a filtration of $A$ and $M$. Let $gr(A) = \bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}} I^i / I^{i+1}$ and $gr(M) = \bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}} I^iM / I^{i+1}M$ be the associated graded ring / module.

Let $\xi_1, \dots, \xi_r$ be the images of $x_1, \dots, x_r$ in $gr(A)_1 = I/I^2$. Then we can  consider the Koszul complexes $K(\xi, gr(A))$ and $K(\xi, gr(M)) = K(\xi, gr(A)) \otimes gr(M)$.

In *Local Algebra*, p.58, (3.3), Jean-Pierre Serre write that the homology modules $H_p(\xi, gr(M))$ are of finite type over $gr(A)$. I do not understand why.

I agree that the modules $K_p(\xi, gr(M))$ are of finite type and that the result would follow from the fact that $gr(A)$ is noetherian, but I don't know if this last fact is true.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $gr(A)$ is generated as an $A/I$-algebra by the finitely many module generators of $I/I^2$, hence is Noetherian by Hilbert basis theorem

Comment: @math54321 Can you make this into an answer, please?

Comment: @Pedro Since the asker has not shown any more interest, I'm not very inclined to expand my comment into an answer. Of course anyone that wants to write an answer is free to use it though